# Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException - Hilt Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-hilt, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm facing this issue while adding hilt dependencies in my project,

error: [Hilt]
Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0
at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:200)
at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:182)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataFactory.create(KotlinMetadataFactory.java:54)
[Hilt]

[image]

**build.gradle.kts (App - level)**

```
 plugins {
     id("com.android.application")
     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
     id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.20-1.0.14"
     kotlin("kapt")
     id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    }

    android {
     namespace = "com.test.testapp"
     compileSdk = 34

     defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.test.testapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.8"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
     }
    }

    dependencies {

       implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
       implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
       implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
       implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
       implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
       implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
       implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
       implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
       implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0")
       implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
       implementation("io.ak1:rang-vikalp:1.0.0-alpha02")
       implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
       implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")
       //navigation
       implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.6")

       //Hilt
       implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
       kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46.1")
       implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")

       //Room
       implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:${rootProject.extra["room_version"]}")
       ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:${rootProject.extra["room_version"]}")
       implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:${rootProject.extra["room_version"]}")

       testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
       androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
       androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
       androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
       androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
       debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
       debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
     }
```

**build.gradle.kts (Project - level)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-    projects/modules.
    buildscript {
       extra.apply {
         set("room_version", "2.5.2")
       }
    }

    plugins {
       id("com.android.application") version "8.0.2" apply false
       id("com.android.library") version "8.0.2" apply false
       id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
       id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44.2" apply false
    }

   tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
      delete(rootProject.buildDir)
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

use the below dependency:

> id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48.1" apply false

---

> plugins {

> ```
> id("com.android.application")
> id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
> id("kotlin-kapt")
> id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
> ```

}

> implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48.1")
> kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48.1")
> kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")
> implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.1.0")

Comment: Yes, 2.48.1 is currently latest. it indeed produces different error. no more metadata stuff